# Questa Error "UI-Msg: (vish-4014) No objects found matching " while running from quartus

Tags: vhdl, quartus, questasim

i am using the simulation tool Questa in combination with Quartus-Prime to develop an project in VHDL. When running the simulation i can execute the testbench but it does not show all signals i have defined inside. When running the same testbench with the same entity on another PC these signals appear in Questa. When try adding the waves by the source files it gives me the error

`# ** UI-Msg: (vish-4014) No objects found matching 'signal_name'`

Some forum posts say that this can be caused by optimizations and that  -voptargs=+acc should be appended to the vsim command. If i run then this command vsim -voptargs=”+acc” -L work -L testbenches/tb_GenericStack tb_GenericStack.tb_Stack from inside the command line without quartus i get the same behaivior that thhe signals are not shown properly. What was recognized from a person that could execute my testbencch on his system is, that the "Objectifilter" Toollbar menu is grayed out and cannot be used on my system if that I am using Fedora 38 and running quartus prime standard 22.1 with questa 2021

Comment: In older versions you had to disable optimization at  the compile-command "vcom" and not at "vsim" ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me. I start questa from inside quartus all normal and in Simulate -> Start Simulation -> Optimization Options i checked "Apply full visibility to all modules(full debug mode)" now i can see all signals and also the Objectifilter in the toolbar works